# Huffman encoding slowing me down

Tags: c#, list, encoding, huffman-code

I think this part of my code is slowing me down. How can I change it so it is faster. I have to read war and piece. it works with smaller samples but will not read war in piece without taking less then 3 hours.

```
while (note.Count > 1)
{
    // this is what I thing is taking the most time, because it loops through your note list, and builds a new list ordered by the node
    // and it gets worse the longer the list is.
    List<Node> orderedNodes = note.OrderBy(node => node.Frequency).ToList<Node>();

    if (orderedNodes.Count >= 2)
    {
        // Takes the  first two groups
        List<Node> taken = orderedNodes.Take(2).ToList<Node>();
        // Create greater node by combining the frequencies 
        Node parent = new Node()
        {
            Symbol = '*',
            Frequency = taken[0].Frequency + taken[1].Frequency,
            Left = taken[0],
            Right = taken[1]
        };
        note.Remove(taken[0]);
        note.Remove(taken[1]);
        note.Add(parent);
    }
    this.trunk = note.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: You can avoid resorting the list by frequency by maintaining it in sorted order. This is probably easiest with a custom linked list structure for this purpose, where changing the frequency of a node shifts it in the list as needed.

Comment: how would I update the nodes with a sorted linked list with out messing the order up?

Comment: seems like you're just merging by adding the frequencies... and then reorder, and repeat ... have a look at roman answer ...

Answer (score 3):

This code has worst complexity like O( N * (N*3 + (N * log N)) ) - at a glance; exact estimate must be even worse.
It is actually quite surprising that it even completes anywhere a little over 3 hours.
By the way, does it even complete processing?

First, implement semantics of 'note.OrderBy(node => node.Frequency)' in a more efficient way, by using a data structure that maintains your nodes in sorted order; or think of other ways to prevent this re-sorting entire list on every round, and then removing two elements from it, and then adding another one.

Second, get rid of any traces of LINQ in this code. You have a tight loop over large dataset, and each round produces at least:

- 5 implicit enumerators
- 5 temporary objects (lists and your nodes)

Third, make sure '.Remove' and '.Add' take const or reasonable time, but not linearly proportional to number of items.

Afterwards, re-check if you still need to optimize further.

Some clues to begin with:

- consider using SortedSet to keep your items in order (it uses a tree internally)
- watch for SortedSet's GetViewBetween for searching, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381801(v=vs.110).aspx
- think maybe you can implement this by maintaining a queue, and having a logical window moving over it - e.g. whether your exact problem is similar to traversing a tree breadth-first
- think maybe you can avoid doing '.Remove' and '.Add' altogether, and instead preallocate all nodes, so that your operation will only update frequency values and change nodes organization

Comment: I guessed that it would take 3 hours. I only let it run an hour and half before getting pissed off at trying to find and fix this part of the code.

Comment: Just for fun, while you're working on improving the algorithm, try running it for over 3 hours, or maybe couple days. Consider using SortedSet<>.